# Sending values from 2 Radiogroups using Bundle passes only the second RadioGroup selected value

Tags: android, bundle, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Hi I am stuck in a very strange code bug. Please Help!!!!
My project has 2 Activities. 
1) The First Activity is a form which includes 2 RadioButtonGroups having 2 Radio Buttons each called 'Yes' and 'No'. Default is 'No'
2) It has a Submit button. 
3) After I click Submit, these 2 radiogroups selected radiobutton text should be displayed on second activity

I am trying to send values from 2 RadioGroup using Bundle object. But it shows the value of the 2nd radiogroup selected for both.

E.g. Radiogroup 1: Select 'Yes' RadioButton
RadioGroup 2: Select 'No' RadioButton

On Second Activity:
Value retreived for RadioGroup1 : No
Value retreived for RadioGroup2 : No

So i tried swapping the code order. its observed that whicheveer radiobutton value code i write last, that value is passed to second activity for both radiogroup. Below is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
    Bundle dataBundle=new Bundle();

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                dataBundle.putString(ConfirmActivity.VARIABLE1, "Yes");                 
                dataBundle.putString(ConfirmActivity.VARIABLE2, "No");                                      
                i.putExtras(dataBundle);



ConfirmActivity:

public static final String VARIABLE1 = "No";
public static final String VARIABLE2 = "No";

String var1 = extras.getString(VARIABLE1);
String var2 = extras.getString(VARIABLE2);



 xml file:

<RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/upasana_no"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RadioGroup>



<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/cd_no"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/btn4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="No"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Simply replace this line public static final String VARIABLE1 = "Yes";

Comment: While passing bundle, your both `key` values are same i.e. `NO`.

Comment: @priyanka...,i have re correct your code not give my own code so as far you have to approve my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same value in `ConfirmActivity.VARIABLE1` and `ConfirmActivity.VARIABLE2` as a result of which the value is being overwritten in `dataBundle`.

Use separate values in `ConfirmActivity.VARIABLE1` and `ConfirmActivity.VARIABLE2`

for eg.

```
public static final String VARIABLE1 = "value1";
public static final String VARIABLE2 = "value2";
```

Comment: Oh Thanks. Done. It's my first time so dint know

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this code :**

```
public static final String VARIABLE1 = "No";
```

**With this :**

```
public static final String VARIABLE1 = "Yes";
```

**Note :** In your code you have override value of key "No" like first set "Yes" and then "No" so finally your both VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2 have same value which is "No".

Answer (score 0):

While passing bundle, your both `key` names are same i.e. `NO`. So it is replacing the previous value. Always make sure to have different `key` names. Otherwise it will override.

Try renaming

```
 public static final String VARIABLE1 = "No";
 public static final String VARIABLE2 = "No";
```

to

```
public static final String VARIABLE1 = "R1";
public static final String VARIABLE2 = "R2";
```

Comment: Glad it helped you. You should accept Apoorv's answer, as he has answered it first.

Comment: @Aniruddha,I have just try to correct her code not given my own initialization as like Apoorv's so how can you advise her to approve Apoorv's ans.